# How to fix Google API, fetch via JavaScript not working due to CORS issue?

Tags: javascript, google-api

I am trying to fetch Google Place API using JavaScript, but I am getting this error message:

`Access to fetch at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=2000&type=restaurant&keyword=American&key=AIzaSyC24tk27gf8Lh1FA0S4-LoMzy8tta4MUWk' from origin 'https://replbox.repl.it' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

How to fix this?

Comment: Could you show how do you request ? Using `xhr`, `jQuery`, `fetch`? A sample of code to demonstrate what you do would help you get your answer.

Comment: https://repl.it/@sungdo1004/BoBJoe